# In Postgres SQL Server 8.4 , how to get number of request times to each table?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres SQL Server 8.4 how to get number of request time to each tables?

For example , what I want is like that

```
   Table_Name      request_time
   person          50
   department      20
```

Plz give me some guideLine.

Comment: Define "access". Disk IOs? SELECTs? Any statement? Does `SET` or `SHOW` or `BEGIN` count if it's any statement? Any DML statement? Any DML + SELECT? What about DDL? What about temporary tables? Do you mean "number of new connections made"? "Number of transactions"? As written this question is too generic to answer.

Comment: Yes , Any statement ..
for example , 1.select * from test; 2.insert into test values("name"). So the result i want to show is table = "test" , access time = "2";

Comment: @Craig Ringer, What i means is request times for each tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [pg_stat_statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html) and/or [csv format logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG) with `log_statement = all` or `log_min_duration_statement = 0`.

There is no way to get statement statistics in a queryable form retroactively. [pgFouine](http://pgfouine.projects.postgresql.org/) can help analyse logs, but only if you've configured PostgreSQL to produce detailed logs.

You probably also want to read about the [statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html) and [associated views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS-TABLE), which will help provide things like table- and index-utilisation data.

Comment: Using pg_stat_statements give me the result what i want.